# SQL Function to LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I want to change the following sql procedure to LINQ to SQL, anyone can help me please.

http://vyaskn.tripod.com/hierarchies_in_sql_server_databases.htm

---

```
CREATE PROC dbo.ShowHierarchy (@Root int) AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @EmpID int, @EmpName varchar(30)

    SET @EmpName = (
        SELECT EmpName 
        FROM dbo.Emp 
        WHERE EmpID = @Root)

    PRINT REPLICATE('-', @@NESTLEVEL * 4) + @EmpName

    SET @EmpID = (
        SELECT MIN(EmpID) 
        FROM dbo.Emp 
        WHERE MgrID = @Root)

    WHILE @EmpID IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        EXEC dbo.ShowHierarchy @EmpID
        SET @EmpID = (
            SELECT MIN(EmpID) 
            FROM dbo.Emp 
            WHERE MgrID = @Root AND EmpID > @EmpID)
    END
END
```

Comment: Which "LINQ" are you talking about? LINQ to Entities? LINQ to Object? LINQ to SQL?

Comment: LINQ to SQL

Thank you for considering

Comment: Would you please check that web page which I posted. I have a requirement same like that function, where I want to populate the data in hierarchic view. 

So far I'hve created same table, same data, same funtion (like in the web page) in SQL Server 2005

So I need the same function to be wriiten in C# with LINQ to SQL

Comment: Yes... so what code did you write up to this point to try this. We are here to help you with programming problems. We are not here to do all your work.

Comment: Just I created OrgDetails.dbml file in my rpoject. 
and declared the objects thats it. sorry I am very new in LINQ so I am confused how to do this.

OrgDetailsDataContext orgDeta = new OrgDetailsDataContext();

Comment: As an aside Aze -- this is a horrible way to solve this problem.

Comment: That is, the right way to solve this problem is to make a stored procedure using a CTE and call it.

Comment: That site is mostly obsolete now ( I stopped reading it back in 2004 or so) it targets SQL Server 7 and 2000. We use CTEs since SQL Server 2995

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way to do the query in SQL Server would be to use [Common Table Expressions (short CTE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx). Write a stored procedure and call it from Linq2Sql. There is no real efficient way to do it in pure Linq except the way Steven outlined (pull out the employer and then recursively call the function) which will result in a fair amount of db queries.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public string[] ShowHierarchy(int employeeId)
{
    using (var db = new YourDataContext("yourConStr"))
    {
        return ShowHierarchyRecursive(db, employeeId, 1)
            .ToArray();
    }
}

private IEnumerable<string> ShowHierarchyRecursive(
    YourDataContext db, int employeeId, int level)
{
    // get the name of employeeId from db

    // yield return that name

    // get the list of people managed by that employeeId

    // foreach employee in that list,
    // call the ShowHierarchyRecursive, and
    // foreach item in the returned list yield return
    // that item.
}
```